# Python Spark join/filter like SQL IN Clause

Tags: python, dataframe, join, pyspark

I have two dataframes with the exact same layout, just spanning different time periods.  

DF1 represents the pre-period and DF2 represents the post-period

| ID | Product | Count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | 1111 | 2 |
| 123 | 2222 | 1 |
| 567 | 1111 | 5 |
| 789 | 2222 | 2 |

I want to isolate the rows in DF1, where the ID exists in DF2.

So, for example, if ID 123 was not present in the post period, DF2, I do not want it to appear in this new dataframe, DF3.

Due to the possibility of multiple ID records in both dataframes, my join logic is duplicating when I try a traditional dataframe join.

I am hoping for an easy way, like in SQL, where you can use the syntax `WHERE df1.ID IN (select df2.id from df2)`

What is the best way to accomplish this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: pyspark has `func.col().isin()` for SQL's `where column in`, but it only accepts array of values. you could however change your logic to an inner join -- `df1.join(df2.select('id').dropDuplicates(), 'id', 'inner')` seems to be the best approach

Answer (score 0):

Use `leftsemi` join if I get you correctly

```
DF1.join(DF2, how='leftsemi', on='ID').show()
```